# Use multiple React useState() hooks to fetch Category title and posts from json api

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect, use-state

I am using React useState() and useEffect to fetch multiple data from an api (`mock-data/my-data.json`).

From the api I want to fetch the *Category Title* and the list of *Posts* and render those in the `jsx`.

Is this the correct way to use `useState()` and `useEffect()` to fetch the data? I made multiple useState constants so after I can render the *Title* and the list op *Posts* in the render method:

```
function ArticleList() {
  const [categoryTitle, setCategoryTitle] = useState('')
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    axios
      .get('mock-data/my-data.json')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
        setCategoryTitle(res.data['title'])
        setPosts(res.data.allItems)
        setLoading(false)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }, [])

  if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading articles...</p>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{categoryTitle}</h1>
      <ul>
        {posts.map(post => (
          <li key={post.id}>{post.titel}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You can use multiple `useState`s and `useEffect`s. Are you getting any error?

Comment: This looks good to me.

Comment: Its the right concept, but avoid call API's directly from a component, its better to create a separated reusable action and service to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks good to me.

If I were to refactor this code, I would prefer to use async/await, and I like to use state enums rather than booleans, for loading/loaded/error states.

```js
function ArticleList() {
  const [categoryTitle, setCategoryTitle] = useState('');
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [state, setState] = useState('loading');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      setState('loading');

      let response = axios.get('mock-data/my-data.json');

      try {
        response = await response;
      } catch (error) {
        setState('error');
        return;
      }

      setCategoryTitle(response.data['title']);
      setPosts(response.data.allItems);
      setState('loaded');
    };

    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  if (state === 'loading') {
    return <p>Loading articles...</p>;
  }

  if (state === 'error') {
    return <p>Error loading articles...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{categoryTitle}</h1>
      <ul>
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <li key={post.id}>{post.titel}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks. Just to understand everything. Why are you using async/await? What are the benefits?

Comment: @meez async/await makes your code a lot neater, easier to read and understand as opposed to chaining promise methods.

Comment: and why are the setter functions not in the `try { //... }` block? `setCategoryTitle(response.data['title']);
      setPosts(response.data.allItems);
      setState('loaded');`

Comment: @mmeez great question! Generally, I try to minimize what I wrap in a try...catch. In this case, I only want to catch an error related to fetching. If an error is thrown while calling setState, then there is a much bigger issue, and the application should probably stop.

Answer (score 1):

Usually its a good idea to use `useReducer` hook instead of using multiple `useState` hooks if you want to set multiple states simultaneously. Your example is that case where you are trying to set multiple states together.
`useReducer` uses reducer function where consolidated state can be manipulated. This makes code more cohesive and more readable in my opinion.
Please see below sample code. For simplicity I have removed axios but you should get the idea.

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-platform-hv6pi?file=/src/ArticleList.js

Comment: My only complaint of `useReducer` is that it is missing thunks.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, this is the correct way. If you wanna use only one useState, you can clone the state object.
For example:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({
  title: "",
  posts: []
});

// For Title
setState({...state, title: "New Title"})

// For Posts
setState({...state, posts: [{...post...}]}
```

But I would like to use lodash clone, immer library or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much it, the only thing that I would highly recommend is use await instead of the famous hadoukens/pyramids of doom, so a plain code would be:

```
function ArticleList() {
  const [categoryTitle, setCategoryTitle] = useState('')
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData(){
    try{
        setLoading(true)
        res = await axios.get('mock-data/my-data.json');    
        console.log(res.data)
        setCategoryTitle(res.data['title'])
        setPosts(res.data.allItems)
        setLoading(false)        
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
    getData();
    }, [])

  if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading articles...</p>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{categoryTitle}</h1>
      <ul>
        {posts.map(post => (
          <li key={post.id}>{post.titel}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: This won't work. You cannot use await inside a regular function, and you cannot pass an async callback to useEffect. Instead, define an async function inside your useEffect callback, and then call it.

Comment: @Benjamin is it somehow possible to render the return statement from: `if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading articles...</p>
  }` in the initial return statement: `return (
    <div>
      <h1>{categoryTitle}</h1>
      <ul>
        {posts.map(post => (
          <li key={post.id}>{post.titel}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )`

Comment: @meez Yes, you could do that using a ternary. However, I would recommend against it. It's much easier to read by using an early return. This is a common pattern when writing functions as well. Exit/return early when possible.